# Karma closes the browser unexpectly

Tags: javascript, angular, automated-tests, karma-runner, karma-mocha

Hi I am using ***Karma + mocha*** to write unit testcases for uicomponents like select, combobox etc...

I am facing a problem where I have about 211 testcases but **Karma** closes the browser unexpectedly before all the testcases are run. 
I made sure that methods such as describe.only, describe.some, describe.skip etc.. are not used.

Screenshot of the log when I run the testcases for the first time.
[image: second time]

Screenshot of the log when I run the same testcases for the second time.
[image: first time]

I have gone through some Karma code and I found out that from socket.io, **"browser_complete**" event is emitted and so karma winds up the server. Why is this happening? How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: I've found creating separate browser window for each test can help find the test case that's not exiting correctly. What have you tried, can you please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for your effort @lloyd. I didn't handle the asynchronous test cases properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue myself. **done** callback was not used for certain asynchronous testcases and since the assertions are included in asynchronous part, the code was not reachable which led to the browser firing **complete** event that resulted in Karma quitting the browser. But I face this issue even now when testcases fails continuously for which I have not found the solution yet. But the problem I have faced above was due to improper handling of asynchronous test cases.